# how to read comments or notes in a google sheet cell by using appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Used below script it is returning null output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/us61X.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, try this:

```
function Cpy_cmt(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  goToSheet('Master_Collection');
  var activeCell = sheet.getRange("AE13")
  var currentCellValue = activeCell.getValue();
  var currentCellNote = activeCell.getNote();
}

function goToSheet(sheetName) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetName));
}
```

Comment: hey john, thanks for your time. unfortunately, I'm getting info output like below 4 ur code :      
10:07:54 AM Notice Execution started
10:07:56 AM Info 
10:07:56 AM Info 
10:07:56 AM Notice Execution completed

Comment: If you are running the function from the code editor that would be the normal message after completion. No errors are being reported, just that it has completed execution. Feel free to add some logger info.